# Do the Mac Pro 2019 (Intel) have a serial number on the external case?

Tags: mac-pro

I have a few "cheese graters" rack mounted and I cannot seem to locate the exterior serial number. I see the older ones have it near the add-on cards but these Intel rack mounted ones have nothing printed on the rear.

Did Apple print this identification anywhere on the outside of the case?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the answer is that it's not located anywhere on outside the machine. Given the rarity of these machines, I think a physical inspection is probably going to be your best bet, but there may simply not be one (strange as that is.)

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, the serial is printed on the bottom of the case:

> Find the serial number printed on the underside of your Mac, near the regulatory markings. On previous Mac Pro models, the serial number is printed on the computer's back panel, below the video ports.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102887

Comment: This seems to be true for laptops but not for the rack mounted version of this computer. The "underside" is the access panel for DIMMs and as far as I can tell nothing else.

Comment: When you say access panel, is it part 13? From my reading and past experience, I would expect the regulatory markings, serial to be etched on number 6. https://support.apple.com/en-us/103968 hopefully it’s not under the rack slides…